# The minimum value displayed on the axis in LiveCharts

Tags: wpf, xaml, livecharts

Why do the lines show from -5?

Can I somehow set up the Line Chart so that when I do not have a value below 0, the chart started with this value?

[image]

Comment: can you provide MCVE?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the MinValue property of the Y Axis to 0.

As I do not know what your code looks like, I have added a snippet below that works.

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY >
            <lvc:Axis Title="TestTitle" MinValue="0"/>  
</lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
```